Why FCC band plans so different from IARU?
I just realized how different the ARRL/FCC band plan is from the IARU Region 2 plan, of which the US is a part. For example, on 40m 2700 Hz modes start at 7.125 vs 7.050 MHz, respectively; on 20m they start at 14.150 vs 14.101. Is there a specific reason for this?
